# How do I add a file to VS2010 template that is not in the project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, project-template

I built a new VS2010 project template (based on MVC2, but it's not important). Most of the files are, of course in the project, but there are a few that are not. For example, T4MVC.setting.t4 and instructions.pdf. Although they are not in the project, I would still want to put them in user directory when new project is created.

However, the files seem to be installed *only* if they are list in .vstemplate **and** .csproj. Is this observation correct? If *no* - what am I doing wrong. If *yes* - is this a bug?

Comment: Unfortunately that is what I have observed. I would vote this question up but I do not have enough rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScottGu](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx) has a step-by-step tutorial how to do exactly what I asked...

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.